# NullPointerException en un sistema de facturacion con Spring-Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, jpa, thymeleaf

estoy haciendo un sistema de facturación en un curso, con Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, JQuery, AJAX, etc. En la clase facturaController tengo un método handler que sirve para guardar las facturas a cada cliente, funciona guardando cada línea de la factura por separado haciendo referencia a un id de la línea, que también contiene un nombre de producto, cantidad y precio, todo bien hasta que intento recorrer las lineas de la factura para guardar los productos y me dice que es null.

Método handler para guardar:

@PostMapping("/form") public String guardar(
Factura factura,

```
           @RequestParam(name = "item_id[]", required = false) Long[] itemId,
                      
           @RequestParam(name = "cantidad[]", required = false) Integer[] cantidad,
                      
           RedirectAttributes flash, SessionStatus sesion){

    if(itemId != null && cantidad != null){
        // este for sirve para guardar cada linea de la factura
        for(int i = 0; i < itemId.length; i++) {
            // busca el producto por su id que lo obtenemos de itemId[]
            Producto producto = clienteService.findProductoById(itemId[i]);

            // estas operaciones se encargan de guardar cada elemento de la las lineas de la factura
            ItemFactura linea = new ItemFactura();
            linea.setCantidad(cantidad[i]);
            linea.setProducto(producto);
            factura.addItemFactura(linea);

            log.info("ID: " + itemId[i].toString() + ", cantidad: " + cantidad[i].toString());
        }
    }else{

        flash.addFlashAttribute("error", "No fue posible cargar la factura. Lo sentimos");
        return "redirect:/listar";
    }


    clienteService.saveFactura(factura);
    sesion.setComplete();
    flash.addFlashAttribute("succes", "Factura creada con exito!");

    return "redirect:/ver/"+factura.getCliente().getId();
}
```

Plantilla de los item de la factura:

```
<tbody id="plantillaItemsFactura">

  <tr id="row_{ID}">

    <td class="d-none">
      <input type="hidden" value="{ID}" name="item_id[]">
    </td>

    <td>{NOMBRE}</td>

    <td>{PRECIO}</td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" value="1" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad_{ID}"
             class="cantidad" onchange="itemsHelper.calcularImporte({ID}, {PRECIO}, this.value);"/>
    </td>

    <td>
      <span id="total_importe_{ID}">0</span>
    </td>
    
    <td class="col-eliminar">
      <!--  se llama a la funcion para eliminar la linea de la factura de autocomplete-productos-->
      <a href="#" class="btn-eliminarFactura" onclick="itemsHelper.eliminarLineaFactura({ID});">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-trash-x" width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#ff2825" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
          <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
          <path d="M4 7h16" />
          <path d="M5 7l1 12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h8a2 2 0 0 0 2 -2l1 -12" />
          <path d="M9 7v-3a1 1 0 0 1 1 -1h4a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3" />
          <path d="M10 12l4 4m0 -4l-4 4" />
        </svg>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: ¿Dónde exactamente da el error?

Comment: No es por desanimar pero el Thymeleaf esta ponco en de uso ya es mas tipico usar Spring puro y otro proyecto de front donde hagas peticiones. Pero dinos donde esta el error e intentamos echarte una mano

Comment: No si eso ya lo se, si es solo por el curso después empiezo a usar angular. El problema es que no encuentro el error justamente no se donde puede estar pero me dice que itemId, la lista que paso como parámetro en el método guardar, es null y no encuentro la causa